# php is incorrectly converting &not in strings to ¬

Tags: php

I need to make up a simple string in PHP which is a string of data to be posted to another site.

The problem is that one of the fields is 'notify_url=..' and when I use that PHP takes the & in front of it and the not part to mean the logical operator AND NOT and converts it to a ¬ character:

```
$string = 'field1=1234&field2=this&notify_url=http';
```

prints as 'field1=1234&field2=this¬ify_url=http'

The encoding on my page is UTF-8.

I have tried creating the string with single quotes as well as double quotes. I have tried making the fields names variables and concating them in but it always products the special character.

This is not being urlencoded because the string is meant to be hashed before the form is submitted to verify posted data.

Comment: That is just browser's output, underlying string is not changed.

Comment: Use `htmlspecialchars()`

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP isn't doing that, it's your browser interpreting HTML entity notation. `&` has a special meaning in HTML as the start of an HTML entity, and `&not` happens to be a valid HTML entity. You need to HTML-encode characters with special meanings:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($string);
// field1=1234&amp;field2=this&amp;notify_url=http
```

Comment: Technically only `&not;` would be a valid HTML entity though, right? This is the browser auto-correcting a perceived error here I think.

Comment: There was some form where the final `;` could be omitted if I remember correctly, but I can't spontaneously find the correct spec.

Comment: Thanks deceze... That was the case. I stupidly believed that special characters do need to the semicolon to make them special characters so didn't even view source. Rookie mistake!