# Part Paypal IPN script and the result below. Why is ["notify_version"]=> string(11) "UNVERSIONED" resulting in ¬ify_version=UNVERSIONED?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

```
var_dump($_REQUEST);

$post_string = '';
foreach ($_REQUEST as $field => $value) {
$post_string .= $field . '=' . $value . '&';
}

$post_string .="cmd=_notify-validate"; // append ipn command
echo "<br>";
print_r($post_string);
```

Results:

array(33) { ["payer_email"]=> string(23) "test@thehouse.com" ["payer_id"]=> string(13) "E45RQXVPLM27E" ["payer_status"]=> string(8) "VERIFIED" ["first_name"]=> string(4) "John" ["last_name"]=> string(3) "Doe" ["address_name"]=> string(8) "John Doe" ["address_street"]=> string(9) "1 Main St" ["address_city"]=> string(8) "San Jose" ["address_state"]=> string(2) "CA" ["address_country_code"]=> string(2) "US" ["address_zip"]=> string(5) "95131" ["residence_country"]=> string(2) "US" ["txn_id"]=> string(17) "4H983006WT017625F" ["mc_currency"]=> string(3) "USD" ["mc_gross"]=> string(4) "1.07" ["protection_eligibility"]=> string(10) "INELIGIBLE" ["payment_gross"]=> string(4) "1.07" ["payment_status"]=> string(7) "Pending" ["pending_reason"]=> string(10) "unilateral" ["payment_type"]=> string(7) "instant" ["handling_amount"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["shipping"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["tax"]=> string(4) "0.07" ["item_name1"]=> string(10) "0229095129" ["item_number1"]=> string(9) "229095129" ["quantity1"]=> string(1) "1" ["mc_gross_1"]=> string(4) "1.00" ["tax1"]=> string(4) "0.07" ["num_cart_items"]=> string(1) "1" ["txn_type"]=> string(4) "cart" ["payment_date"]=> string(20) "2020-02-29T14:53:31Z" ["notify_version"]=> string(11) "UNVERSIONED" ["verify_sign"]=> string(56) "A5MeNvwAzPFh5JqP6rDJjWuwlDQMASFBt55XfwPuOvYZNBYtXWEz.z1h" }

payer_email=test@thehouse.com&payer_id=E45RQXVPLM27E&payer_status=VERIFIED&first_name=John&last_name=Doe&address_name=John Doe&address_street=1 Main St&address_city=San Jose&address_state=CA&address_country_code=US&address_zip=95131&residence_country=US&txn_id=4H983006WT017625F&mc_currency=USD&mc_gross=1.07&protection_eligibility=INELIGIBLE&payment_gross=1.07&payment_status=Pending&pending_reason=unilateral&payment_type=instant&handling_amount=0.00&shipping=0.00&tax=0.07&item_name1=0229095129&item_number1=229095129&quantity1=1&mc_gross_1=1.00&tax1=0.07&num_cart_items=1&txn_type=cart&payment_date=2020-02-29T14:53:31Z¬ify_version=UNVERSIONED&verify_sign=A5MeNvwAzPFh5JqP6rDJjWuwlDQMASFBt55XfwPuOvYZNBYtXWEz.z1h&cmd=_notify-validate

Comment: I finally found the answer here, same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49150723/php-is-incorrectly-converting-not-in-strings-to-%C2%AC